# MySQL update with IN clause and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run some updates on my MySQL database. Here is the query that I want to use:

```
UPDATE `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl` 
SET `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl`.description = '&lt;div class=&quot;dwrp&quot;&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;F. Locker $109.99&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;Nike Outlet $109.99&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;Ch. Sports $107.99&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;Hoopers Hookup $89.99&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;h2 class=&quot;special&quot;&gt;These prices as of 11/20/13&lt;/h2&gt;'
WHERE `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl`.id in (
    SELECT `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl`.id FROM `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl` 
    INNER JOIN `wphh_wp_eStore_cat_prod_rel_tbl` 
        on `wphh_wp_eStore_cat_prod_rel_tbl`.prod_id = `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl`.id
    WHERE `wphh_wp_eStore_cat_prod_rel_tbl`.cat_id = 5
    )
```

This generates the following error:

> `#1093` - You can't specify target table 'wphh_wp_eStore_tbl' for update in FROM clause

Why? I know in MSSQL I can do this:

```
Update tableone 
set columnname = 'xxx' 
where id in (
    select id 
    from tableone 
    where category = 10)
```

and it works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to enclose the `in` list in an additional level of nesting.  MySQL will then materialize the data:

```
UPDATE `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl` 
SET `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl`.description = '&lt;div class=&quot;dwrp&quot;&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;F. Locker $109.99&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;Nike Outlet $109.99&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;Ch. Sports $107.99&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;Hoopers Hookup $89.99&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;h2 class=&quot;special&quot;&gt;These prices as of 11/20/13&lt;/h2&gt;'
WHERE `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl`.id in (
    select * from (SELECT `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl`.id FROM `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl` 
INNER JOIN `wphh_wp_eStore_cat_prod_rel_tbl` on                 `wphh_wp_eStore_cat_prod_rel_tbl`.prod_id = `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl`.id
WHERE 
`wphh_wp_eStore_cat_prod_rel_tbl`.cat_id = 5) t
    )
```

Another way is to use `join` to with `update`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MySQL guy but could you do this instead? I also like using table alias with these ugly names.

```
UPDATE `wphh_wp_eStore_tbl` e
inner join `wphh_wp_eStore_cat_prod_rel_tbl` ecpr
  on ecpr.prod_id = e.id
  and ecpr.cat_id = 5 
set e.description = 'Some Text To Update With'
```

In SQL Server the "from" and the join come after the SET but.. not the case in mySQL apparently.